# Source item not found by source code: default and sku:

Tags: magento2.3.0

When I try to ship an order that has the word "leash" in the `SKU`, this error message appears.

```
Source item not found by source code: default and sku:
```

All I can do is offline credit memo the order to change it from "`Processing`".

My store was migrated from a 1.9.0.1 installation. But it appears to only be SKUs with the word "`leash`" in them... all other `SKUs` seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've probably found this link, but it does look like a known issue with Magento 2.3.0 and they're working on it. If a temporary workaround is to be had it'll be revealed here:

https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2043

**Update:** I was able to make this error go away and allow shipping orders by turning off Magento managing stock.

Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Manage Stock

Set this value to "No" and you can bypass the error.

This does prevent Magento from managing your stock, so if your flow relies on Magento reducing your stock on hand when an order ships, don't change this setting. In our case we do not need Magento to worry about stock values so the fix worked for us. If you do need this feature, you'll need to follow the issue report at the link above and watch for either an update to Magento or a shared hotfix.

Comment: Thanks! I disabled Manage Stock while I shipped the order, and re-enabled it after :)

Comment: can we have a custom code to manage this issue from custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Configurable with Custom Options? If no, then I believe the ticket https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2043 would not solve your problem.

Also, please be aware that Disabling Stock Manageability to process an order, you don't compensate the initial reservation created at the time of Order placement. So that the Salable quantity could represent incorrect value.

Read more about this logic here - https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

Comment: Nope no custom options

Comment: @Igor: I have had custom options configured to the configurable products where the "manage stock" is already turned off but still I am getting the error while trying to generate the invoice.